# Parsing second DNS from IPCONFIG /all, Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dns

I'm quite new to batch files and I'm trying to do something decently advanced and am trying to figure out how to identify and parse the second line under DNS SERVERS in IPCONFIG /all. If the answer is quite advanced, I would appreciate it greatly if you could explain it thoroughly. Here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set adapter=Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection
set adapterfound=false

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig /all`) do (
    set item=%%f
    if /i "!item!"=="!adapter!" (
        set adapterfound=true
    ) else if not "!item!"=="!item:DNS Servers=!" if "!adapterfound!"=="true" (
        rem echo DNS: %%g
        set Globaldns=%%g
        set adapterfound=false
    )
)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%m in ("%Globaldns%") do set Globaldns=%%m
echo DNS: %Globaldns%
```

If someone has two DNS servers set, I need a way to pull the second DNS address and store it in a second variable, the code above is able to pull the first DNS but I have not figured out a way to pull the second. Thank you for your help!!

EDIT:
Another piece of information. This needs to be able to be run on anything from Windows Vista to Windows 10 and it needs to be able to target a specific connection (we are only reconfiguring Ethernet devices, no wireless) So we need to be able to use the adapter's connection name to parse (i.e. Local Area Connection,Ethernet).

Comment: ipconfig output is difficult to parse, may be easier with `wmic nicconfig list DNS /format:CSV`

Comment: See edit, I do like your answer but I need a way to cherry pic a specific connection out and I can't realistically use the adapter name. Is there a way to add the connection name to it? (I.e. Local Area Connection #, Ethernet #)

Comment: This is dificult for me as I have a different locale and so my namings don't match. What output does `getmac /fo csv /v` return?

Comment: `netsh interface ip show dnsservers name="Local Area Connection 2"` might also be useful

Comment: How does the output of `ipconfig /all` look like in case there are two DNS servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130434/parsing-second-dns-from-ipconfig-all-windows-batch#comment69467237_41130434) is right, `ipconfig` output is difficult to parse. Parsing `wmic` output *could be* easier.

Take a look at [Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx) and their [`wmic` aliases](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) `NIC` and `NICCONFIG`, respectively.

For the first identification, use `wmic NIC get /VALUE`. Note the `/VALUE` switch and notice the `NetConnectionID` property: *name of the network connection as it appears in the **Network Connections** Control Panel program*. Then, parse output from

```
 wmic NIC where "NetConnectionID = 'Local Area Connection'" get Index, MACAddress
```

to get `Index` property (*index number of the Windows network adapter configuration. The index number is used when there is more than one configuration available*) value to a varible, e.g. `_index` and use it as follows:

```
wmic NICCONFIG where "Index = %_index%" get /Value
```

For easier parsing, you can narrow output to only desired properties and change format to `csv`, for instance

```
set "_properties=DefaultIPGateway,DHCPServer,DNSServerSearchOrder,IPAddress,IPSubnet"
wmic NICCONFIG where "Index = %_index%" get %_properties% /format:CSV
```

Please notice and apply Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266).

**Edit**: fixed a mistake with `path` keyword:

- `NIC`       is a `wmic` alias for `path Win32_NetworkAdapter`
- `NICCONFIG` is a `wmic` alias for `path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`

so e.g. next commands represent the same [˙WQL˙ query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
wmic NICCONFIG                              where "Index = %_index%" get /Value
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where "Index = %_index%" get /Value
```

Comment: When I run the "wmic path NICCONFIG where "Index = %_index%" get /Value" command with the correct index number instead of the variable it errors out unless I remove path. What does path do?

Comment: @user7253664 answer fixed,  sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: How can I go about parsing the output of "wmic NIC where "NetConnectionID = 'Local Area Connection'" get Index, MACAddress" for just the index?

Comment: Also why does this code echo the command and not the output of the command, what am I doing wrong?

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=" %%f in ('wmic NIC where "NetConnectionID = 'Local Area Connection'" get Index, MACAddress') do (
    echo %%f

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=" %%f in ('wmic NIC where "NetConnectionID = 'Local Area Connection'" get Index^, MACAddress') do ( echo %%f )` [Omit `usebackq` option](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and [escape the `,` comma](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the question but this powershell script might help, albeit I don't know if it will work back to vista.

```
gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "netconnectionid is not null"|
  %{ gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration `
    -filter "interfaceindex=$([int]$_.interfaceindex)"|
      select -expandproperty DNSServerSearchOrder}
```

As I have only one dns server configured my result is proper but meaningless.

Comment: It appears that the OP wants to get information for only wired connections. Is there a property that will reveal that?